# PHP - Generating a unique ID based on server hardwares/OSes/environments?

Tags: php

Is it possible to generate a unique ID based on server hardware/OS? I want to generate license keys for my PHP web app based on customer server, just like Atlassian JIRA does.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why can't you use the current timestamp??

Comment: @Mayilarun that's hardly collision-proof now, is it?

Comment: If I use the current time-stamp, the user can use that license key on several other servers. The license ID must be generated based on server specs so that it will not be valid for other servers.

Comment: @Cem How much room is there to manoeuvre on the possible OSes? Will it always be *nix, always Windows, or a mix of both/+others?

Comment: Take a look at [`php_uname()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-uname.php) and maybe try combining that with the MAC address? Disadvantages of MAC address is that they can be spoofed, you will need to re-issue licenses if the user changes their NIC(s) and you need an external program/library to get them. But they are approaching unique (they *must* be unique to a given network), and to combine the MAC with the uname would make it difficult to spoof. It would not be impossible, but then pretty much nothing is impossible to spoof, plus you are writing in an open-source language anyway.

Comment: Dave, thanks. php_uname will make the trick. I am building a nice PHP app and it will be ioncube encoded. Therefore, it's difficult to reverse engineer the license key algorithm. Thanks for your suggestions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to read several [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) / [`$_ENV`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php) variables and combine them to a string. After this md5 this string and you will have your license key.

You have to be careful on which variables to choose if you do not want your customers to get a new license key everytime they update their servers. Also not all variables are available on all system configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way is to code an EXE in any other language that gets the HWID from the server, and then have your PHP script exec() the EXE, if the output from the EXE matches then you run the script... If not, you show an error.

You might want to use blenc_encrypt() in PHP at the very least so that you can prevent users from going in and changing "if (systemhwid == validhwid)" to "if (1 == 1)"

A better option for encryption is to use IonCube (I think it's Ioncube that encrypts PHP files) but unfortunately it costs lots of money.

Search PHP.net for the blenc_encrypt() function

To those who avoid questions by saying things like "a web server is not meant to do that" or "you don't need to verify HWID on servers", JUST ANSWER THE QUESTION! Don't just say it isn't possible, because my answer proves it IS possible... You just need to think outside the box, and you need a little thought. Also, don't question the user's intent, they just want a straight answer, no BS.